# Cannot write to home directory/files when logging in via SSH with public key

Tags: ssh, permissions, remote, key-authentication

I have been `ssh`ed into a remote host on and off all day, but suddenly can no longer write anything to my home directory despite having appropriate permissions. Read operations work fine, but attempting to modify existing files or directories or create new ones gives me `Permission denied` errors.

After some trial and error (involving accidentally issuing `ssh` on the remote host to itself, which doesn't have my private key) I've narrowed the issue down to only occurring if I authenticate via public key.

Forcing password login with

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.com
```

gives me a perfectly functional session where I can write as normal.

This behavior has me completely baffled, especially since I've never had a problem logging in with public key authentication before (and it was working fine ~5 minutes before the problem started).

EDIT I should add that I do not have administrator access of any sort to the remote system. I've confirmed via an administrator that the permissions are also correct viewing as root, but they are also completely at a loss for what the problem might be.

Comment: Are you the only system's administrator and the only one with access to your account?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an admin at all on the remote system. I should add that to the question.

Comment: The first thing to check is obviously what was last changed and there are many places where additional security layers could be added.  I suggest you start by contacting the admin.

Comment: When you cannot write to your own `$HOME` and you are still logged in then you should check what user you are logged in as with `id`.

Comment: @MartinSugioarto Both the writable (password auth) and unwritable (key auth) connections generate the same output with `id`. Also the file permissions are definitely the correct owner and group (both by name and uid/gid).

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that the user directories are mounted on login (custom solution). Or it's perhaps an NFS mount. Maybe the user info is not propagated to the NFS server correctly. But these are only a rough guesses. This is definitely something the admin needs to solve.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is your home directory on? What kind of account management does the server use? Run `df ~` and `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` and `uname -a` on the server and copy-paste the output.

Comment: I know this is months later, but after having given up on the problem for a while it was suggested to me that, perhaps, my home directory being in an AFS cell might be part of the problem (essentially agreeing with the general suggestions from @MartinSugioarto and @Giles). A quick check of the documentation revealed that getting AFS tokens is automatically done with SSH password authentication, but has to be done manually if you authenticate via another method.

Comment: The reason it stopped working suddenly is because I had not shifted my SFTP client to use keyauth, so every time it connected it was resetting the AFS token timeout. Once I configured it to use keys the problem appeared as soon as the most recent AFS token expired.

Incidentally, as far as I can tell, there is no way to avoid having to type your password at least once per [token TTL] when dealing with AFS.